# Restricting website folder and sub-folder access to registered users

Tags: php, permissions

I am using a PHP script from [Funky Visions UK](http://funkyvision.co.uk/viewphpscript4.html)
And it is working well for allowing users to register and create usernames and passwords, etc.

But I can't figure out how to restrict a specific folder and sub-folders to the registered users.

Comment: you should never let users access to the actual website file system. that is prone to traversal attacks.

Comment: Please contact the support of that script, not us.

Answer (score 0):

you can always create index.php file in each folder and do a session check. i.e

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
 {
 redirect to other page
 }
 else
 {
 do nothing
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are actually tying to do - if they should just be able to download files or something from the folders, then just create a login system using your users, and only allow access to the files when they are logged in.

eg very very basic something along the lines for each folders

```
<?php  if (!$_SESSION['valid_user']) exit('No direct script access allowed');
....otherwise list the files
```

But more information about what you are trying to do what help you get a better answer.